# Remove DC offset from a sine wave

Tags: signal-processing

I am performing FFT signal processing on a sine wave for which I have to remove the DC offset from the signal. How can I do so in C++?

I tried using a-mean(a) where a is the sine wave, but it gives incorrect results. In MATLAB it is very easy using the detrend function.

Comment: If you are doing FFT analysis, why do you need to remove the DC offset? You can just ignore the DC offset once you have the signal in frequency domain.

Comment: I know this is old, but because the frequency domain waveform will show a spike in the first array elements of the signal,  ignoring it (at least if using the NI signal processing libraries/VIs) would result in incorrect values for intended peak power/frequency.  (i.e., peak power/frequency would show up around the zeroth array element.) The C/C++ solution could be as simple as taking the average of all values in the waveform array, then subtract that average from every element in the array.